# What can cause Twig to be slow?

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Twig for large-scale project and I have located after a lot of profiling that Twig causes a particular slow-down in script execution.

If I removed the Twig piece of the code it can execute in around 0.03 seconds. With the Twig piece put back in it executes in 0.1 second.

I'm only using basic Twig features such as:

- Print/echo {{ SomeVar }}
- Loops {% for Item in Items %}
- And if-statements

The templates are quite short in code and the loops have at most 8 iterations.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what may cause this slow-down? Or is it simply how Twig is and should I instead accept this?

Comment: You should avoid using Twig, since it messes up the MVC principle.

Comment: The parsing taking time, Twig and most template engines in nutshell are expensive for runtime. The solution is just to cache the rendered template, so Twig won't do render each request cycle

Comment: @MichaelArenzon Thanks for your answer - That would be my "Plan B", but I hoped there was another thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Can you provide an article or something else to explain how Twig messes up MVC? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarkHünermundJensen it shouldn't be really "Plan B", since caching in general is good practice plus there's no really any good reason for why giving Twig/whatever-engine do the render each request. When you do deployment, just make the system also delete all the cached templates.

Comment: The problem is I can't cache everything. A page showing a customer's orders for instance has to be dynamic, so he would be able to view his new order(s) instantly. But the frontpage is what drags this particular project a lot down, and that's fortunately cachable :)

Comment: Do you cache the compiled template? IIRC it's disabled by default, and enabling it can speed up twig considerably.

Comment: @MarkHünermundJensen AFAIK both Twig and Smarty are not rendering the templates with the end values, rather than that they are just compiling into php code, so basically you'll just have a compiled template that is plain php. Each time you'll set variables for Twig, instead of doing this rendering each time, php's interpreter already does this job for you

Comment: just turn off/comment one by one and found what slow down your render, that it. cause some methods can trig an expensive method/classes that can be checked with naked eyes. all need to be measured part by part!